# Facing problem with user profile url scheme like example.com/username in django

Tags: django, django-urls, user-profile

In a django app, I need to create twitter user profile urls with following structure like:

- `example.com/<username>`
- `example.com/<username>/friends`
- `example.com/<username>/blog`
- `example.com/<username>/some-page`
- `example.com/<username>/some-other-page`

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('profiles.views',
    url(r'^(?P<account_name>[a-zA-Z0-0_.-]+)/$', 'show_profile', name='profiles_show_profile'),
    url(r'^(?P<account_name>[a-zA-Z0-0_.-]+)/friends/$', 'show_friends', name='profiles_show_blog'),
    url(r'^(?P<account_name>[a-zA-Z0-0_.-]+)/blog/$', 'show_blog', name='profiles_show_blog'),
)
```

My first problem is that while `example.com/<username>` works fine `example.com/<username>/any-other-page` does not. They all end up at `show_profile` view instead of their own view.

**Note:** Everything works fine if I make urls change the url structure to `example.com/user/<username>`

What am I doing wrong here? Please advise.

Secondly, I would like guidance on django best practices(pitfalls, gotchas etc) in dealing with url schemes where first part is itself is variable.

Thanks

Comment: The `0-0` in your regex is odd: I think you mean `0-9`, though that isn't your problem.

Comment: Yes, Was a typo in my code. Fixed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why your URLs aren't working.  You can try moving the first pattern to the end, so that other patterns have a chance to match first.  The problem you're describing sounds like `example.com/user/any-page`, the pattern is matching "user/any-page" as the account name.  The regex you show wouldn't do that, but maybe your actual code is slightly different?