# Django - how to implement an example.com/username url system

Tags: django, url

I am trying to implement on my website a simple and friendly address system.

What i'm thinking about is when the user logged in, his username will be displayed in the address bar.

> - www.example.com/username**1** (for home page profile)
> - www.example.com/username**1**/about/
> - www.example.com/username**1**/gallery/

> - www.example.com/username**2** (for home page profile)
> - www.example.com/username**2**/about/
> - www.example.com/username**2**/gallery/

And additionally if anyone enter the address www.example.com/username1, will be shown the profile of user1.

I already implemented a register/Login system using Django-Allauth

> mySite/urls.py

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

> home/urls.py

```
url(r'^$', views.index),
```

> home/views.py

```
def index(request):

return render_to_response('home/index.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I tried to follow some examples like [Facing problem with user profile url scheme like example.com/username in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694795/facing-problem-with-user-profile-url-scheme-like-example-com-username-in-django)

But i dont have this thing working yet. I dont understand what to do :(

Please, give some advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following url as the **last** item of the `mySite/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/', include('userapp.urls')),
)
```

Then the `username` parameter will be passed to the views of your `userapp`:

`userapp/urls.py`:

```
from userapp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.profile, name='user_profile'),
    url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='user_about'),
    url(r'^gallery/$', views.gallery, name='user_gallery'),
)
```

`userapp/views.py`:

```
def profile(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    return render(request, 'userapp/profile.html', {'profile_user': user})

def about(request, username):
    ...

def gallery(request, username):
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Excellent answer Catavaran!

Comment: @catavaran what if this solution has to applied in already working django application. Won't it lead to lot of changes?

Answer (score 1):

It's almost perfect, but i have a bug. Let me explain. When i login (my login system is: django-allauth) on the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/` i return to `http://127.0.0.1:8000` with an error 404.

I am not getting the http://127.0.0.1:8000/username/ with the template, when the login botton is clicked.

The instalation of django-allauth require adding to the settings.py

> LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

How can i redirect to http://127.0.0.1:8000/username/ and show the correct template?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Regarding**

> How can i redirect to

Based on the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20143515/4992248

```
# settings.py:
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'project.your_app.allauth.AccountAdapter'

# project/your_app/allauth.py:
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class AccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

  def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
      return 'request.user.username'  # probably also needs to add slash(s)
```

Would be better to use `get_absolute_url`, ie `return 'request.user.get_absolute_url'`. In this case you need to do:

```
# 1. Add `namespace` to `yoursite/urls.py`
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/', include('userapp.urls', namespace='profiles_username')),
)

# 2. Add the code below to the Users class in models.py
def get_absolute_url(self):
    # 'user_profile' is from the code shown by catavaran above
    return reverse('profiles_username:user_profile', args=[self.username])
```

**2. Regarding**

> show the correct template

`catavaran` wrote correct urls which leads to `views.profile`, so in `view.py` you need to write:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import UserProfile  # import model, where username field exists
from .forms import UserProfileForm  # import Users form

def profiles(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, username=username)

    return render(request, 'home/profiles.html', {'user_profile_form': user})
```

In template (i.e. `profiles.html`) you can show user's data via `{{user_profile_form.as_p}}`