# add username to url in django

Tags: python, django, url

I've been trying to add the URLs of the system with the user name as a parameter in them, but it did not work for me, I've seen some reviews here and it did not work for me the way as they have done or solved their problem.

views.py

```
@login_required
def profile(request, username):
    User = get_object_or_404(user, username=username)
    return render(request, 'dashboard/Profile.html', {'profile': User})
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
```

if need, here is my forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\w+$', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=     {'class': 'form-control'}),
    label=_("Username"), error_messages={'invalid': _("This value must be contain only letters, number and undescores.!")})
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), label=_("Email Address"))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), label=_("Type your password"))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), label=_("Retype your password"))
```

[image: This is the error that the system shows me]

[I tried with these posts and it does not work for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533096/django-how-to-implement-an-example-com-username-url-system)

Comment: The error is happening on your /dashboard page. You should show the view and template for that page.

Comment: You're hitting `/user/dashboard`, not `/profile/$USERNAME`, so your `profile` view never gets called, and the router can't figure out where to route the request.

Comment: now i type the correct url and show this error http://prntscr.com/cdtmtm

Comment: check the first line of your profile function