# Adding username in url after base url in django

Tags: python, django

I am working on django project(which is at verge of completion) and I have structure like something below:
project name: Mysite
App name: myapp

project urls : 127.0.0.1/myapp/blog etc

my requirement is to exclude my app from website (through out) and adding usernames in profile page like:

- 127.0.0.1/blog
- 127.0.0.1/products
- 127.0.0.1/search

and for profile page:
127.0.0.1/simer123/myprofile

I have took from various SO questions and able to exclude the "myapp" part from my urls. 
and Also able to include "username" in url for specific page. 
[SO question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533096/django-how-to-implement-an-example-com-username-url-system) [SO question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694795/facing-problem-with-user-profile-url-scheme-like-example-com-username-in-django) these questions really helped and I found a way out to include user name in my url.

But now again I am stuck because throughout the project I have used things like:

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('myapp:myprofile'))
```

And similarly in template part like:

```
<a href="{% url 'myapp:myprofile' %}">
```

How can I manage to convert them?

Can Anyone explain this with some example.

Thanks

**Update:**
urls.py file in mysite folder looks like below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^autocomplete/', include('autocomplete_light.urls')),
    url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.index'),
    url(r'^', include('myapp.urls', namespace="myapp")),
    url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls', namespace="myapp")),
    url(r'^admin/login', adminLogin),
    #url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', views.serve),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
    }),
    url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/', include('myapp.urls', namespace="myapp")),
    url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/myapp/', include('myapp.urls', namespace="myapp")),
]
```

urls.py in myapp folder includes urls like below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /myapp/
    url(r'^autocomplete/', include('autocomplete_light.urls')),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='user_about'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^newaccount/(?P<uid>.*)/$', views.newaccount, name='newaccount'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^myprofile/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
]
```

Comment: can  you post your urls.py

Comment: @levi I have updated my question.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `kwargs dict` to your `reverse` and `reverse_lazy` function in order to mapping it with your url pattern.

```
reverse_lazy('myapp:profile', kwargs={'username': username})
```

And in your template, just pass it as positional argument

```
<a href="{% url 'myapp:profile' username %}">
```

Comment: Thanks @levi. Let me implement your solution to check if it works otherwise I will post my urls.py in question.

Comment: this gave me an error:Reverse for 'myprfile' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'username': 'simer'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: I have this url included in my myapp urls.py :  url(r'^myprofile/$', views.myprofile, name='myprofile'), and I have def in views,py as def myprofile(request, username). I got error as : Reverse for 'myprofile' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'username': 'simer'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: @Simer Fixed, you need to change `myprofile` for `profile`, cuz your url pattern anme is profile not myprofile. So, this is the correct pattern `myapp:profile`

Comment: I have profile and myprofile both but none of them match. Please see my updated question. Thanks for your help @levi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120661/discussion-between-levi-and-simer).

Answer (score 1):

Your base url doesn't need to mention `myapp` at all, just set your url that includes `myapp` to `r'^'`. You can still namespace the urls and everything the same as before.